# TCP connection reset occurs when WSGI app responds before consuming environ['wsgi.input']

Tags: python, http, tcp, paste, wsgiref

For our webservice, I wrote some logic to prevent `multipart/form-data` POSTs larger than, say, 4mb.

It boils down to the following (I've stripped away all WebOb usage and just reduced it to plain vanilla WSGI code):

```
import paste.httpserver

form = """\
<html>
<body>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
    <input type="file" name="photopicker" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
"""

limit = 4 * 1024 * 1024

def upload_app(environ, start_response):
    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
        if int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0')) > limit:
            start_response('400 Ouch', [('content-type', 'text/plain')])
            return ["Upload is too big!"]
    # elided: consume the file appropriately
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    return [form]

paste.httpserver.serve(upload_app, port=7007)
```

The logic shown works right when unit tested. But as soon as I tried sending actual files larger than 4mb to this endpoint, I got errors like these on the client side:

- `Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.` from Google Chrome
- `The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.` from Firefox

Same error occurs when using Python built-in `wsgiref` HTTP server.

Fact: once I added `environ['wsgi.input'].read()` just before responding with HTTP 400, the connection reset problem went away. Of course, this is not a good fix. It just shows what happens when you fully consume the input.

I perused [HTTP: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925090) and found some interesting guidelines on how it was important to mangage TCP connections carefully when implementing HTTP servers and clients. It went on about how, instead of `close`-ing socket, it was preferred to do `shutdown`, so that the client had chance to react and stop sending more data to server.

Perhaps I am missing some crucial implementation detail that prevents such connection resets. Insights anyone?

See [the gist.](http://gist.github.com/281530)

Comment: I did some more digging online.

Turns out limiting body size gracefully is poorly addressed.
Nginx author Igor Sysoev has a write up about this: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://sysoev.ru/web/upload.html

To summarize: you have to perform a "lingering close" dance, where server sends the error response, shuts down the socket for writing, and waits for client for a while in order to avoid just killing connection out right.

Comment: Another pertinent link: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-http-connection-00#section-8 It advises that HTTP server should close "half of the connection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are discarding the input stream without reading it, and this is forcing it closed.  The browser has queued up a good portion of the file to be sent already and then it gets a write error because the server closes the connection forcefully.

There is no way around this that I know of without reading all the input.

I would recommend some Javascript to test the size of the file before it is sent.  Then the only people who get the error are those who are ignoring the client-side check because they don't have Javascript or because they are purposefully trying to be malicious.

Comment: Unfortunately, without ActiveX, Java or Flash on client side, you can't interrogate the input element on the form even when you look for innocent things like size of selected file.

Comment: @Pavel Repin, I didn't realize that about Javascript.  That's unfortunate.  I will point out though that my answer is still basically correct, even if it's not a happy answer.  :-)